# Any set of $d$ points in projective space is the zero locus of polynomials of degree $d - 1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

> Show that if $\Gamma \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ consists of d points and is not contained in a line, then $\Gamma$ may be described as the zero locus of polynomials of degree $d - 1$ and less.

This problem is exercise 1.3 from Joe Harris's *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course*. I don't so much want an answer to the original question as some help *understanding* it. My issue is a general unfamiliarity with projective geometry, and I think some concrete examples might help me better make sense of the situation.

More specifically, just above this problem the book states that for a line $L \subset \mathbb{P}^n$,

> ...it's not hard to see that a polynomial $F(Z)$ of degree $d - 1$ or less that vanishes on $d$ points $p_i \in L$ will vanish identically on L.

But I'm not sure what it means in any useful, algebraic sense for points in projective space to be collinear. I can't even seem to put together for my own use three collinear points in $\mathbb{P^3}$ to see *why* (in a simple numeric sense) every quadratic equation that is zero at all three of them will also be zero everywhere else on the line.

Comment: For an example of three collinear points, take [0:0:0:1], [1:0:0:1], and [2:0:0:1].

Comment: This shows how dreadful that book by Harris is: its third exercise already  is unmotivated and undoable by its  claimed target  consisting of beginners in algebraic geometry. There is a solution floating on this site, but since you are not really interested I won't say more :-)

Comment: Re: why every quadratic equation that is 0 at 3 points. I'm in the same boat as you and am trying to understand this god forsaken book. If we take the points $p_i$ to actually be points (and not lines in $\mathbb{P}^n$), then I reasoned that if it had three vanishing points on that line and did not vanish identically on $L$, then somehow from that we could make a quadratic that had three roots, which is impossible